# from import python code doesn't work correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I created a module as `mathfunctions.py` including four functions, then created another module in which call one function from `mathfunctions.py` through `from...import code`.
When I run the second module, all four functions were executed.

my first module:

```
def add (x,y):
return x + y
x = int(input("Please Enter the first number:"))
y = int(input("Please Enter the second number:"))       
result = add (x,y)
print ("The result is:" , result)

def subtract (x,y):
return x - y
x = int(input("Please Enter the first number:"))
y = int(input("Please Enter the second number:"))       
result = subtract (x,y)
print ("The result is:" , result)

def multiply (x,y):
return x * y
x = int(input("Please Enter the first number:"))
y = int(input("Please Enter the second number:"))       
result = multiply (x,y)
print ("The result is:" , resudelt)

def division (x,y):
if y != 0:
    return x / y
else:
    print ("Please Enter the correct number:")
x = int(input("Please Enter the first number:"))
y = int(input("Please Enter the second number:"))       
result = division (x,y)
print ("The result is:" , result)
```

my second module:

```
from mathfunctions import add
add (x,y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your code and read this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please share us your code

Comment: If you call the functions in mathfunctions.py, they'll be executed when you import the file. Place the calls under a `if __name__ == '__main_'` condition or remove them.